# How to Register ILogger(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging) with DI usinq autofac .net framework

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, autofac, ilogger

I use ILogger from Microsoft.Extensions.Logging in a .net framework project.
Now I want to register the ILogger in the container but i cant.All the answers are about .net core.
i try

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

//first try
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Logger<>)).As(typeof(ILogger<>));
IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();

//second try
services.AddSingleton(typeof(ILogger<>), typeof(Logger<>));
IContainer container = builder.Build();

httpConfig.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
```

also my class is

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    private readonly ILogger<TestController > _logger;
    private readonly IService _service;

    public TestController (IService service, ILogger<TestController > logger)
        {
            _service = service;
            _logger = logger;
        }
}
```

The di is correct because other services have injected correct.
When i include the logger in constructor i get the message 
An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'TestController '. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.

Comment: Could you share the full stack trace ? it looks like Autofac is not being used

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since trying to integraten with those extensions, consider populating the service collection is expected and populating the builder once everything is registered,

Example from docs

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();

// The Microsoft.Extensions.Logging package provides this one-liner
// to add logging services.
services.AddLogging();

// Once you've registered everything in the ServiceCollection, call
// Populate to bring those registrations into Autofac. This is
// just like a foreach over the list of things in the collection
// to add them to Autofac.
builder.Populate(services);

IContainer container = builder.Build();

httpConfig.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
```

#### Reference [Autofac: .Net Core Integration](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/netcore.html#net-core)

Comment: thank you very much,i see that but i believed it is only on .net core but is works also for .net framework

Comment: @dimmits explained this is not a .net core app he's working on.

Comment: This WILL work in .Net Framework 4.7.2. It should be noted that you will need nuget package Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection